# Android Material Design working with Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

Android Material Design working with Tabs.
All of the Fragment are visible?
In other words, all of the onStart() method is called at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

No they are not usually two at the beggining ,
I was using Material Tab host and my logs were suggesting that it was calling 4 onCreates() of the fragments  one of the visible fragments and 3 of the upcoming fragments in the tabhost realted view pager